# How to create a console script using if __name__ == ' __main__' condition?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am creating a setup file for python script installation. Commonly, the documentation use for example the next setup file:

```
from setuptools import setup

# setup.py file
setup(name='test',
      version='0.0.0',
      packages=['test'],
      entry_points={
      'console_scripts': [
              'test = test.test:main'
           ]
         },
      )
```

to call this:

```
# test/test.py file
def main():
    print('Hello!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But, my problem is that I have my "main" code function below the *if __ name__ == '__ main __'* condition. I Can not create a main() function because this represents a big change an effort of development

Are there any solution? or I have to spend time creating a main() (or any name) function?

Comment: Do you understand *why* the `__main__` stanza is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you've got a bunch of code that you want to call only when the file isn't being imported (that's what that if statement does). However, it'd be very annoying, I'm sure, to add a tab before each line.

Solution: use something like [this (works if you have linux; sure there are alternate solutions)](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/insert-tab-at-beginning-of-each-line-in-file-and-other-sed-questions-824459/), which is `sed -i 's/^/\t\t/' <filename>` on a separate file with your main code copy-pasted in to add tabs. Copy paste this tabbed code into your `def main():` and voila.

However, it looks like this is just meant to be imported, and that's why you're using the setup.py file...in which case you don't need to do this, because presumably you *want* this code to run, and that's why you're importing it. (Unless it's some testing stuff.)

Comment: No, is not so simply like add Tabs. If you have some time, you can have a look to this repo that I am working: https://github.com/eamanu/Aping/blob/master/aping/aping.py. I tried to change def main(): for if ...  but this give other error that I want to avoid.

Comment: @EmmanuelArias see my last paragraph then - skimming your code, none of it seems to be "loose" i.e., outside of a class or a function, so it looks like something purely intended to import. In which case, you do not even need the `__main__` stanza.

Comment: mmmm, yes you are right. I could change the if condition directly by the main(), and in this way I could make the "console_script" con setup file.